# What does "Invalid URI: The URI is empty" error mean in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm a total newbie in SharePoint(2010)

I've been given a VM with a development envirnment already setup with the SharePoint site deployed.

So if I log in as Administrator, I can get to the main page. And I add in my dev account as an administrator.
Now when I try to login with my account to the top sitecollection landing page, I get error: access denied.
Now I go back in and add myself as an owner under SiteName Ownders.  I log back in and this time I do not get the Access: Error Denied error. But now I get the yellow screen with this error: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.

Funny how adding myself as an admin in the Site Collection Admins section did not get me this far.

```
The stack trace says: [UriFormatException: Invalid URL: The URI is empty]
System.URI.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, Urikind urikind) + 7225919
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(string requestUrl) +83
.
.
.
```

Comment: Does is give you a correlation ID? If so, you can use that to get more info from the ULS log --> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS

Answer (score 0):

Yes, firstly you should check the Logs as suggested by @Ola Ekdahl and also check whether the site Master Page is in draft mode, if so checkin the master page and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I actually needed to make myself admin in another site collection it was trying to read a list value from.